# JPa/Hibernate/JUnit: How to use a proper method of reflection in the ToString?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, junit, apache-commons-lang

i would like to test my services in an architecture Spring/JPA/Hibernate via JUnit.

All is ok for moment, but i used an overriding method of ToString to verify the content :

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return ToStringBuilder.reflectionToString(this, 
                    ToStringStyle.MULTI_LINE_STYLE);
}
```

It uses the library commons.lang. The result is correct, but when I check my entities that have relationships (Set for @ OneToMany or @ ManyToMany) it quickly becomes unreadable.

Anyone knows there a way to make JUnit test result more readable in the console?

Thank you.

Comment: So you convert your entire object to a string and verify it against some expected string?

Comment: i make some request in JUnit test (getById, getAll, insert, update, delete) and test some asserts. Then, i want to log in the console some results (ex: List of get methods). => `  for (Language language : allLanguages) {
   logger.info(language.toString());
  }
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [Lombok](http://projectlombok.org) annotations [`@EqualsAndHashcode`](http://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode.html) and [`@ToString`](http://projectlombok.org/features/ToString.html).

`@EqualsAndHashcode` helps to avoid bugs and `@ToString` give you a nice readable output for `toString()`.

You can exclude fields you don't want in them:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude={"someManyToManyCollection", "dontMather"})
@ToString(exclude={"someManyToManyCollection", "dontMather"})
```

or make them use only a field you are interested:

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(of={"id", "someKey"})
@ToString(of={"id", "someKey"})
```

This should allow you to get your readability with `toString()` and you can compare the objects with `yourEntity.equals(otherEntity)` in your tests.

Comment: You're welcome! Note that I just now realized the second example was using the wrong variable name and fixed it. :)